# Content Type Inconsistent - Refiners and Fetched Property - SharePoint 2010

Tags: content-type

Is it time to submit a support ticket?

My goal is to scope and refine search results by content type and to present the content types with the object in the search results. I all of these "working" but my  custom content types are not consistently applied to my objects, instead I see that sometimes SP has substituted mimetype instead of my content type.

It appears completely random or as though there is a conflict of some kind. Some of my custom content types are applied to all of my objects correctly, some applied to no objects at all and some applied to some objects.

I have created multiple custom content types including Policy, Procedure, Process Map...etc.. I created a new managed property “mycontenttype” and mapped the crawled properties Basic:5(Text) and ows_ContentType(Text) in that order to it…then executed a full crawl twice. I have since backed out the Basic:5 mapping and executed a full crawl with the same results.

Using mycontenttype in the search scopes works correctly and the refiners I receive work correctly and appear in the search results themselves (after adding a fetch for mycontenttype), but I can see in the search results that not ALL of my objects have my content types... instead mimetype is in mycontenttype "sometimes" as I described above.

I am assuming a full crawl completely resets all relevant indexes? I am out of ideas except going the route of a support ticket.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been resolved in our environment. In parallel we were implementing a content type hub for the first time in this farm. The CT Hub was implemented and a full crawl then executed. All content types (custom and oob) are now available as refiners and as fetched items in the object search results. We did not have to republish any content types but we did publish a few newly created to test the CT Hub. Prior to the CT Hub all custom content types were created at a site level.